# ZeroMQ - Get user ID from ZeroMQ Auth response

Tags: zeromq, zeromq-auth

In ZeroMQ, more precisely cppzmq in my case, when you use ZAP,
it is handled completely transparently for the user.

However, as documented in the RFC: https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec/27/,
the Auth server can send back a user ID and some metadata in the response:

> The reply message SHALL consist of the following message frames:
>
> - An address delimiter frame, which SHALL have a length of zero.
> - The version frame, which SHALL contain the three octets “1.0”.
> - The request id, which MAY contain an opaque binary blob.
> - The status code, which SHALL contain a string.
> - The status text, which MAY contain a string.
> - *The user id, which SHALL contain a string.*
> - The metadata, which MAY contain a blob.

A little bit further down, it precises the meaning of *user id*:

> *user id*: this MAY provide the user identity in case of a 200 status, for use by applications. For other statuses, it SHALL be empty.

**My question is the following: how can you retrieve the user ID from the response with cppzmq?**

Small code example to show what I mean:

```cpp
void client() {
  zmq::context_t context;
  zmq::socket_t socket (context, zmq::socket_type::req);
  socket.set(zmq::sockopt::zap_domain, "global");
  socket.set(zmq::sockopt::plain_username, "user");
  socket.set(zmq::sockopt::plain_password, "password");

  socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:4242");
  ...
  std::string auth_user_id = /* magic function here */;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal empty reference implementation is provided in the RFC repository at https://github.com/zeromq/rfc/blob/master/src/spec_27.c. This implementation demonstrates a server talking to a proxy handler over inproc://, talking to an external terminal handler over TCP. The terminal handler implements a PLAIN authentication mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not sure you understood my question...
I can use Authentication just fine, and it works. My problem is getting the Auth answer _metadata_ from the authentication request.